# How to update a field type of json

Tags: go, struct, go-gorm

I have a table which has a column of JSON type.

```
type test struct {
        ID *string `gorm:"id" json:"id"`
    LeadScoreComponents *datatypes.JSON `gorm:"lead_score_components" json:"lead_score_components"`
}
```

So it can expect values like null, JSON and empty array. How can i update its value.

I pass model in gorm updates function then it is not updating for null value

```
q.Model(&test).Where("id = ?", id).Updates(test)
```

When I convert it to map[string]interface{} and try to update it is breaking when any JSON value is present in it.

db_error: sql: converting argument $2 type: unsupported type map[string]interface {}, a map

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to unmarshall the retrieved record, then add field to it, marshal it back, and then save it

```
var record test
q.Where("id = ?", id).First(&record)

var data map[string]interface{}
json.Unmarshal(record.LeadScoreComponents.RawMessage, &data)

// Modify the desired field in the map
data["fieldName"] = "updatedValue"

jsonData, _ := json.Marshal(data)
record.LeadScoreComponents = datatypes.JSON{RawMessage: jsonData}

q.Save(&record)
```

To store exclusively `null` value,

```
var record test
q.Where("id = ?", id).First(&record)

// Set the JSON field to null
record.LeadScoreComponents = datatypes.JSON{RawMessage: []byte("null")}

q.Save(&record)
```

NOTE: along with `encoding/json`, `gorm.io/datatypes` package is needed for it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `datatypes` package is your package, you can implement the `Scanner` and `Valuer` interfaces for your `datatypes.JSON` struct ([official documentation](https://gorm.io/docs/data_types.html#content-inner)).

```
// datatypes package
func (j *JSON) Scan(value interface{}) error {
  bytes, ok := value.([]byte)
  if !ok {
    return errors.New(fmt.Sprint("failed to unmarshal JSON value:", value))
  }

  result := json.RawMessage{}
  err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &result)
  *j = JSON(result)
  return err
}

func (j JSON) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
  if len(j) == 0 {
    return nil, nil
  }
  return json.RawMessage(j).MarshalJSON()
}
```

With this, when you try to save, update or retrieve any field of type `datatypes.JSON`, it will be automatically resolved to the appropriate types.

If the `datatypes.JSON` is a struct from a 3rd party package, you can always implement your own type (for example, `MyJSON`), implement the `Scanner` and `Valuer` interfaces for the `MyJSON` type, a use the `MyJSON` type in your code.

```
type MyJSON datatypes.JSON
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't update a `dataypes.JSON` with a `map[string]interface{}`.

simply take the string representation of the value that you want, and cast it to `datatypes.JSON`.

like so:

```
newTest := &test{
  ID: "123",
  LeadScoreComponents: datatypes.JSON(stringValue)
}
q.Model(&test).Where("id = ?", id).Updates(newTest)
```